# MySQL Case with Insert and Update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, innodb

I need help writing a conditional query to copy data from one table to another, everything was pretty straight forward until I decided I wanted to include versioning in my application!

I have looked at some of the examples, but they are mostly oriented towards creating a mysql procedure, this is what I have tried:

```
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT `version`
                FROM `archive_courses`
                WHERE `original_course_id` = '$course_id'
                AND `version` = '$current_version'
            )
            THEN
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO `archive_course_users`      <------ syntax error
                    (`course_id`, `user_id`, `course_qty`)
                    SELECT @new_course_id, '$user_id', `course_qty`
                    FROM `current_course_users`
                    WHERE `course_id` = '$course_id'
                    AND `user_id` = '$user_id'
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE `archive_course_users`
                    SET `course_qty` = (SELECT `course_qty` FROM `current_course_users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id')
                    WHERE `original_course_id` = '$course_id'
                    AND `user_id` = '$user_id'
                END
            END
        END
```

It seems the case is working /OK/ but throws a syntax error when it gets to my `INSERT` query. **How should I be doing this?**

Comment: you can't use case in **insert**, but you can use case in **insert select** statement (`INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM table1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Rahul's answer I created two queries:

```
    //INSERT IF NOT EXISTS
        INSERT INTO `archive_course_users`
        (`course_id`, `user_id`, `course_qty`)
        SELECT @new_course_id, '$user_id', `course_qty`
        FROM `current_course_users`
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT `version`
            FROM `archive_courses`
            WHERE `original_course_id` = '$course_id'
            AND `version` = '$current_version'
        )
        AND `course_id` = '$course_id'
        AND `user_id` = '$user_id'

    //UPDATE IF EXISTS
        UPDATE `archive_course_users`
        SET `course_qty` = (SELECT `course_qty` FROM `current_course_users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id')
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT `version`
            FROM `archive_courses`
            WHERE `original_course_id` = '$course_id'
            AND `version` = '$current_version'
        )
        AND `original_course_id` = '$course_id'
        AND `user_id` = '$user_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't work as well that way. Change your query to be like

```
               INSERT INTO `archive_course_users`     
                (`course_id`, `user_id`, `course_qty`)
                SELECT @new_course_id, '$user_id', `course_qty`
                FROM `current_course_users`
                WHERE `course_id` = '$course_id'
                AND `user_id` = '$user_id'
                AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM `archive_courses`
            WHERE `original_course_id` = '$course_id'
            AND `version` = '$current_version');
```

Comment: This works for the other queries I have to tackle, but how would I include an update statement in this method? Thanks!

Comment: NO, you can't certainly punch in a UPDATE + INSERT that way. With the answer I have provided make 2 separate query one for insert and another for update. Else, use `Insert on duplicate key update ...` feature. See documentation.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `"insert.. on duplicate key update"` ?

Heres an example from the mysql manual:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Hope it helps

Comment: This was my first thought, but the `version` column isn't a primary or unique key :(

Answer (score 0):

Cannot have statements inside a `SELECT`.  So either

Move the code out of the `SELECT`:

```
 IF (...) THEN   -- Note:  No "CASE"; not "WHEN"
     INSERT ...
 ELSE
     UPDATE
 END IF
```

Or `SELECT` some kind of flag, then use an `IF` statement outside.