# Is it possible to use an IF statement in PHP along with different sql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, if-statement

Basically I want to update a value in the table if the date field is equal to todays date, otherwise I'd like to insert a new row into the table if the date is not equal to today. Say for example something like (I know syntax is wrong here) -

```
if($date == $today){
   $sql = $con->query("UPDATE table SET field= 'field+$value', field2='field2 + $value2' WHERE id=2")
}else{
     $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2,field3)VALUES('{$value1}', '{$value2}', '{$value3}')");
}
```

How would I go about doing something like this? is using an if statement like this in php/SQL queries possible? or is there a different way that it has to be done?
Cheers.

Comment: Do it exactly as you have shown above

Comment: Have a look at [on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: @Epik What are you talking about?

Comment: Is it possible to use an IF statement in PHP along with differnet sql queries? Yes it is. The example code is a valid way to do this. Other commenters also note that it's not necessary since you can achieve the same result using only MySQL.

Comment: You could use a duplicate key update if you were willing to add a foreign key onto the date column.

Comment: As it is the update query is unlikely to do what you want it to do, and the insert query is invalid. Is that the actual problem you're having?

Comment: Are `$value` and `$value2` integers? If so don't quote them, and don't quote column names, column names use backticks.

Comment: you should check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023397/mysql-case-with-insert-and-update using CASE will be merely sql

Comment: Are we all talking amonst `$ourselves`? *lol* seems like it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Grammar Nazis are so 40's, isn't it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please don't fix code in questions. If you think there's a problem with the code, write an answer.

Comment: So I can do it this way?? or not lol?

Comment: @Juhana I fixed an irrelevant typo, its not related to the real question and was generating unnecessary answers/comment totally unrelated to the real question. I would not have done it without a lot of thought and then only if I thought it was of benefit to the questioner getting a relevant answer instead of a lot of rubbish

Comment: @RiggsFolly Since the if syntax is valid, we don't know what the real problem is. The OP might just as well have a problem with the query and has misdiagnosed the issue.

Comment: ...yeah and I'm the one who got flack for it earlier, but that comment to me was deleted. Too many cooks in the kitchen here.

Comment: @Juhana But he does not, that is just a throw away bit of code to demonstrate the question, which is basically _Can I write an IF like this to control 2 different queries being run in the right way at the right time_

Comment: @eth3king Yes you can do it exactly like you have suggested. But in future be careful when asking a question. Rep hungry members will pounce on anything they see that might consitute an answer that will garner them a Tick or an Upvote Even when it is apparent to most that the error is Totally Irrelevant

Answer (score -2):

Your logics works as is, fix the code to be valid `(field1, field,2,field3)` is `(field1, field2,field3)` I imagine, and it will work as expected.